# Python 3.x: Extract front cover from FLAC file and save

Tags: python, flac

I was trying to learn the basics of Python during the last months and I found many answers on stackoverflow. But now it's time to ask my first question because I can  not find anything helpful.

I have a FLAC audio file and want to extract the front cover and save it to the hard disk using python 3.x. I read the documentation of mutagen, audiotools, eyeD3 ... but I still can not figure out where and how the information is stored.

Could anyone provide a code snippet, please?

Thank you very much.

```
from mutagen.flac import FLAC, Picture

song = "Anathema - Empty.flac"

var = FLAC(song)
pics = var.pictures
print (pics)
for p in pics:
    if p.type == 3:
        print("\nfound front cover") 
        # how can I save the picture???
```

Comment: " I read the documentation of mutagen". The Mutagen docs have [clear information](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/flac.html#mutagen.flac.FLAC.pictures) on how to extract images from FLAC files.

Comment: Please try to write some code and post your attempts here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. I have some problems understanding the classes and how to use them correctly. That's why I'm dependent on examples.

Comment: Just write [`p.data`](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/flac.html#mutagen.Picture.data) to a file. Open a file with mode `wb` and write to it. There is an example of reading in the docs you just have to write instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution. Thank you very much for your help!

```
from mutagen.flac import FLAC, Picture

song = "Anathema - Empty.flac"

var = FLAC(song)
pics = var.pictures
print (pics)
for p in pics:
    if p.type == 3: #front cover
        print("\nfound front cover") 
        with open("cover.jpg", "wb") as f:
            f.write(p.data)
```